# JS - Call function by name (in object notation)

Tags: javascript, window, eval, object-notation

I want to clean up some old code and optimize it, which often uses the same code. (with only different names of functions to call)

I make a easier example and no, I don't write on a game. But this example looks more comprehensible to explaination of my issue.

```
character.sleep(1);
character.changeName(name);
character.useItm(1423);
```

Easier Example:

```
object.function(parameters)
```

Target was something like this:

```
myFunc(funcName,value) {
    character.{funcName}(value);
}

$('.btn_sleep') { myfunc('sleep','1'); }
$('.btn_cName') { myfunc('changeName','Harold'); }
$('.btn_uItem') { myfunc('useItem','1423'); }
```

First I thought about to use eval(), because no user-input will come near of this functions. But I dislike this idea because of the performance lost.

Then I looked around for alternatives and found **window[]** and **new function()** as solution.

But I dont get an idea how to use it, when I want to dynamcially call a function by name in an object-notation. *(Or in worser cases, when you've to get the result for an if-condtion from a function, which you called with object-notation.)*

Could anyone help?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dynamically access object property using variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/dynamically-access-object-property-using-variable)

Comment: Thank you, that was it! And so fast, nice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way I know how to dynamically call functions is using bracket notation because it allows you to set your object path with a variable

```
function myFunc(funcName,value) {
    character[funcName](value);
}

myfunc('sleep','1');
```